# iOS 13 UISplitViewController - Compact View Controller

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller

So I'm currently evaluating using the UISplitViewController, but had accidentally been trying out the iOS 14's version. Aside from the 3 column's displays, I also noticed in XCode there's an option in the Storyboard called Use Separate View Controller for Compact Width's.

I tried this out and it does seem to work pretty flawlessly. However it doesn't appear to be an option in the iOS 13's UISplitViewController.

Is this something can be done through code? I just find it a little jarring with the iOS 13's one when you display it on an iPhone, it shows the Detail page with the back option.

Our iPhone App's main layout is a UITabViewController, we are exploring the UISplitViewController for the iPad version and wanted to make use of it as the main full size iPad's display and then have it be able to fall back to our UITabViewController when it's in a compact width state.

Comment: Your goal is a good one, but the primary, secondary, and compact columns are purely an iOS 14 innovation. Earlier, you’d have to do this the old way.

Comment: @matt what's the old way to fall back on a different view controller or swap out when it's in Compact Width?

Comment: So you’re not willing to do any research? Adaptive split view controllers were introduced in iOS 8. They are well documented and there are lots of books and articles and videos about them. And Stack Overflow entries. It isn’t my job to teach it all to you again. I’m just answering the question you asked, about backward compatibility.

Comment: For example https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/

Comment: @matt I apologise in advance, but I wasn't asking for a painted picture, just the correct name of the feature would have been enough, I couldn't find it based on the terms I was searching for, thanks for the link I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

if we want to set it in code behind , we just need to set the style like following

```
MasterViewController controller = new MasterViewController();

this.SetViewController(controller, UISplitViewControllerColumn.Compact);
```

Comment: This will only work on iOS 14, I was more asking how would you achieve the same result in iOS 13?